# Converting a value into NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have this ticks value `"634758517020305000"` which corresponds to 21st June 2012. I tried to convert the tick value into NSDate object like this:

```
NSString *str = @"634758517020305000";
NSInteger offset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:
                 [[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])] intValue]]
                dateByAddingTimeInterval:offset];
static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
if (dateFormatter == nil) {
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    NSString *fourDigitYearFormat = [[dateFormatter dateFormat] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"yy" withString:@"yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:fourDigitYearFormat];
}

// There you have it:
NSString *outputString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

But I got the output: `1/19/2038`. If anyone knows where I am doing wrong, please let me know.

Comment: what is the source of "634758517020305000"?

Comment: am getting it from webservice. It is the value returned after sending mail.

Comment: It's not even a Timestamp..It is giving invalid date when trying to convert..What exactly is the above value ? Is it any kind of float value of entire date ?

Comment: its not unix time, so what is it?

Comment: BTW, doing a [str intValue] overflows a 32-bit integer.  You need to do [str integerValue] which returns an NSInteger.

Comment: @TimPotter Careful, his tags indicate iOS, in which NSInteger is also 32-bit.

Comment: Ooh, good point @borrrden.  I was poking around in Mac OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Unix timestamps` is wrong. it should be **1340236800** 
check your Unix timestamps [Here](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)

Comment: Thank u. Yes i checked already.Will check the webservice once again.